# Fade word in one sentence loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a loop where I am able to fade just one word out of one sentence but have failed to execute. I have looked the way to do it in this exact platform and just changed for what I needed so I don´t know if there is a problem with my code itself of a syntax error. Please help.

```
<DOCTYPE>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

```js
$(function(){
var words = [
'personas',
'comunidades',
"infraestructura"
], i = 0; // i for counting

setInterval(function(){
$('#changeText').fadeOut(function(){ //fadeout text
$(this).html(words[i=(i+1)%words.length]).fadeIn(); //update, count and fadeIn
});
}, 2000 ); //2s
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="cover">
    <div id="cover-caption">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="fullscreen-bg">
        <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
          <source src="Loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
          </video>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="cover-text">
       <h1>Nosotros construimos <span id=changeText>más que robots</span></h1>
     </div>
   </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: Yes it says "$", and "setInterval" are not define

Answer (score 2):

I just removed all the redundant code and it appears to work. *Why do you importing jQuery three times by the way?*

```js
$(function(){
var words = [
        'personas',
        'comunidades',
        "infraestructura"
        ], i = 0; // i for counting

    setInterval(function(){
        $('#changeText').fadeOut(function(){ //fadeout text
            $(this).html(words[i=(i+1)%words.length]).fadeIn(); //update, count and fadeIn
        });
    }, 2000 ); //2s
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="cover">
    <div id="cover-caption">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="fullscreen-bg">
                <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
                    <source src="Loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
                </video>
            </div>  
        </div>
          <div class="cover-text">
           <h1>Nosotros construimos <span id=changeText>más que robots</span></h1>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

Without cancer:

```js
const words = [
    'personas',
    'comunidades',
    "infraestructura"
];
let i = 0; 

const change = () => {
  changeText.classList.add("fade");
  changeText.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
    changeText.textContent = words[i = (i + 1) % words.length];
    changeText.classList.remove("fade");
    setTimeout(change, 1500);
  }, { once: true });
};
setTimeout(change, 1000);
```

```css
.fadeable {
  transition: opacity linear 0.5s;
  will-change: opacity;
}

.fadeable.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="cover">
  <div id="cover-caption">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="fullscreen-bg">
        <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
                    <source src="Loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
                </video>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cover-text">
      <h1>Nosotros construimos <span id=changeText class=fadeable>más que robots</span></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

<sub>(Furthermore, i believe that jQuery should never be used.)</sub>